# Output procedurally generated (or externally streamed) audio on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm looking at developing an application for the WP7 platform which accepts an audio stream from a computer and outputs that stream on the phone speaker. This involves either dealing with the audio encoding / decoding myself, or somehow passing off an audio stream to the WP7 platform.

I've struggled so far to find any raw audio output API's and I am not sure what I have to do on the server (computer) side to get the phone to just deal with the audio stream.

I have looked at a few MSDN articles, but I can't quite tell if they do what I want. If somebody could point me in the right direction that would be great!

I think the [MediaStreamSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource%28VS.95%29.aspx) class does what I'm looking for, and the [MediaStreamSource.ReportGetSampleCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource.reportgetsamplecompleted%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method appears to confirm this, but nowhere does it say clearly that it can be used for raw audio.

If you need any information, or if you have any suggestions of better ways to do this that would also be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `XNA.Framework.Audio` namespace [`SoundEffect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.soundeffect.aspx) to get a soundeffect instance from a raw audio stream. Which should usually be a standard PCM format.

[This post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598930.aspx) on microphone by Charles Petzold could be useful.
An excerpt

> In contrast, classes in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio namespace
>   work with uncompressed audio data in the standard PCM format, which is
>   the same method used for audio CDs and Windows WAV files.

Comment: Thank you! This should be exactly what I need